# How to achieve this behaviour with Varnish vcl language (directors dictionary by key)

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have tried everything I could think of, nothing worked, here what I need to do:

I have a rather complex application that relies on a list of "nodes" that are able to serve content depending on the user account, I have many nodes.

Let's say I have these nodes "**n**":

- n1
- n2
- n3

And these accounts "**a**" (with their files "**f**"):

- a1: f1, f2
- a2: f3, f4
- a3: f5

Not all nodes stores all of the files, so, for instance here how files are stored (files can be stored on one or many nodes, depending on account storage redundancy):

```
 n1:   , f2, f3,   , f5
 n2: f1,   , f3, f4, f5
 n3: f1, f2,   , f4,
```

As you can see here, every file is available on 2 nodes.

Now when the customers access its content: `GET /account/{a1}/files/{f1}` I need the varnish to being able to forward my user to either **n2** or **n3**.

The issue here is that I need a lot of directors "**d**" (one per file):

- d1: n2, n3
- d2: n1, n3
- d3: n1, n2
- d4: n2, n3
- d5: n1, n2

And of course this list is completely dynamic (not an issue with some redis-event based configuration generator or consul-templates), but picking up the right director is hell (assume url for picking file is `GET /account/{aX}/files/{fX}`):

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.url ~ "/files/f1$") {
    req.backend_hint = d1.backend()
  }
  else if (req.url ~ "/files/f2$") {
    req.backend_hint = d2.backend()
  }
  else if (req.url ~ "/files/f3$") {
    req.backend_hint = d3.backend()
  }
  else if (req.url ~ "/files/f4$") {
    req.backend_hint = d4.backend()
  }
  else if (req.url ~ "/files/f5$") {
    req.backend_hint = d5.backend()
  }
}
```

The app serve thousand of files, so this if/else is somewhat impossible to maintain..

What I thought doing is something a bit more evoluted (but couldn't find a way with varnish vcl languange), for instance define a dictionary (pseudo code):

```
sub vcl_init {
  # pseudo code down here
  set directors_dict = dict(
    "f1"=[d1],
    "f2"=[d2],
    "f3"=[d3],
    "f4"=[d4],
    "f5"=[d5]
  )
}

sub vcl_recv {
  set req.http.file_id = regsub(<extract file id from url>)
  set req.backend_hint = directors_dict[req.http.file_id]
}
```

Please feel free to ask for details, I'll be glad to provide them.

Answer (score 0):

So, the Enterprise version has `vmod_kvstore` packaged (https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/kvstore/#get-backend), but you will need a subscription or to grab and run an official instance image (AWS market or whatever cloud platform you use, if you use one)

Alternatively, there's this vmod I wrote some time ago: https://github.com/gquintard/libvmod-stendhal, but you'll have to check it works for your version, compile it and install it yourself.

Comment: I indeed saw the premium package, but I'd like to avoid if possible. I will take a look at your module !